# fetch pictures with mongoose with a certain parameter

Tags: express, mongoose, axios

Hi and thanks for all the people willing and ready to help me out !

I have a mongoose Model like so :

```
const pictureSchema = mongoose.Schema ({
    pictureName : String,
    creator : String,
    description : String,
    img : String,
    createdAt : {
        type : Date,
        default : new Date(),
    },
    themeLinked : String
    
})
```

Now what i am trying to do, is to fetch all the documents that have a certain specific value for "themeLinked". it's like sorting all the entries in my documents that have the same "themeLinked".

so what i did, from my front-end react App, i sent the value of theme linked as a req.param. so it is sent to my back end with the GET request.

and in my back end, in the controller i wrote this code :

```
const fetchPictures = async (req,res) => {
    const  {themeId} = req.params;
    try {

        const pictures = await pictureModel.findOne({themeLinked : themeId});
        res.status(200).json(pictures)

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(404).json({ message : err})
    }
}
```

and in the network Tab in my chrome browser, i get 'null' as a value for Response.

so beeing a begginer i am struggling to find the right way to fetch all the pictures that have the same 'themeLinked' value....this must be pretty simple but i'm struggling

thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

ok i got, it, all i needed to do was :

```
const fetchPictures = async (req,res) => {
    const  {themeId} = req.params;
    try {

        const pictures = await pictureModel.find({themeLinked : themeId});
        res.status(200).json(pictures)

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(404).json({ message : err})
    }
}
```

for Obvious lexical reasons, findOne only returns one entry, as find returns all entries that have the same matching 'themeLinked' value....:)